# Placing of "be" vis-a-vis a "...ly" adverb in a sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, adverb-placement

I have seen many English writers in India preferring to place "...ly" adverb before "be" in a sentence . They abhor placing "...ly" adverb immediately after "be".

For example, they prefer to write:

> ... this could slowly be done.

rather than writing:

> ... this could be slowly done.

Is there a grammatical basis to support such preference? Is the other one wrong?

Comment: Grammatically I don't think there's any fixed rule governing the position of ***slowly***, but idiomatic preference massively favours putting it at the end - [*can be done slowly*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=can+slowly+be+done%2Ccan+be+slowly+done%2Ccan+be+done+slowly&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccan%20be%20done%20slowly%3B%2Cc0) is practically infinitely more common than either *can slowly be done* or *can be slowly done*.

Comment: Sir, I agree that "...can be done slowly" is a better construction. But, let us narrow ourselves to the question: why do they out of the two constructions "... this could slowly be done" and "... this could be slowly done" prefer the former one? Is there a grammatical basis? Is "... this could be slowly done" equally correct from the grammatical point of view?

Comment: I think you misunderstood it from somewhere. Nobody would say putting *slowly* before *be* is better/preferable than putting it after *be*. People say "I am happily married" or "I am married happily" showing their wedding rings and they don't say "I happily am married". It doesn't work that way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is based on misunderstanding.

Comment: There could be a telic/atelic issue here.  Is adverb placement the same for telic and atelic verb phrases?  I like "slowly be done" better than "be slowly done" but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Rathony: My first reaction to that is - surely one of the most important aims of ELL is to disabuse querents of misunderstandings? In this case I must admit that although as a native speaker I know perfectly well where I can and where I can't vary the position of any given adverb (and if * *can*, whether the position affects meaning in any way), I can't offhand rattle off an answer summarising that knowledge. And I can't easily explain why adverb immediately after [TO BE] doesn't always work, but it's fine in, say, *He was immediately arrested and handcufffed*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The OP is asking  "why many English writers in India prefer to place "...ly" adverb before ***be*** in a sentence". Your example places the adverb after the verb *be* in *He was immediately arrested ... The question was asked based on the OP's misunderstanding. Nobody would advocate placing an adverb before be in any country. "He immediately was arrested" doesn't work even if it makes sense.

Comment: @Rathony: [*After weaning has been accomplished the child can **gradually be** given more solid food.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+child+can+gradually+be+given%22). More examples [*could **easily be** found*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22could+easily+be+found%22) to show that adverb *before* [TO BE] can sometimes be acceptable and/or preferred. For example, [*I had a bowl of cereal with milk and **suddenly was** overwhelmed with a sleepy feeling.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22and+suddenly+was+overwhelmed%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think there is a bit of misunderstanding between us here. Those examples placed the adverbs before be because there is a modal verb involved (both positions are fine in the first two examples). The third example with "suddenly" has nothing to do with the position of the adverb. Suddenly means "immediately after I had a bowl..."  and it should be placed before "was". That's the rule. The OP is asking if putting the adverb before ***be*** in whatever situation (regardless of auxiliary verbs or rules) is preferred by many English writers in India. That is wrong.

Comment: @Rathony: We've definitely got some kind of misunderstanding. *Suddenly means "immediately after I had a bowl..." and it should be placed before "was". **That's the rule.*** I have no idea what "rule" you're talking about, or how you square it with the fact that the sequence [*and **was suddenly** overwhelmed*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22and+was+suddenly+overwhelmed%22) is over 25 times more common than [*and **suddenly was** overwhelmed*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22and+suddenly+was+overwhelmed%22).

Comment: @FumbleFingers There are 2 different meanings/usages of suddenly. The first post of the first link shows that suddenly modifies "overwhelmed" by another surge of panic. The second, third, fourth, fifth..., the first page of the first link are all passive voices with an agent after "by". It has nothing to do with the action of the previous clause. However, the example with "***suddenly was*** overwhelmed" has the cause of "overwhelming" in the previous clause, i.e. the reason he was overwhelmed with a sleepy feeling is he had a bowl of cereal with milk.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Different constructions. You can change "suddenly" to "immediately after he had a bowl...". but your new posts (in the first link) can't be changed (at least the first page of it). The second link are mostly compound sentences where there are reasons/causes that caused (might have caused) the action in the second clause, i.e. in "Martin Luther... said that... he accidentally left out the word enim (“for”) in one passage..., and suddenly was overwhelmed with the feeling..." the cause was the fact that he left out the word. There are clear distinctions in the two links' usages.

Comment: @Rathony: Gimmie a break! I've got an honours degree in "English Language & Literature with Linguistics", and even ***I*** have trouble seeing the distinction you're making! The idea that this is some kind of "clear-cut rule", and the implication that OP's failure to understand this rule somehow justifies peremptorily closing the question seems unreasonable to me. It is after all a *learner's* site.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As you know, we need five votes and at least one member agrees with me. I have looked through all the links of "was suddenly" usages. The second page and third page don't show any examples but covers. I just assume that most of them would be passive voices with agents of the verb *overwhelm* after ***by*** or ***at***.  The difference is there. In "I entered the intensive care unit, saw the room where you died, and ***suddenly*** was overwhelmed with the memory of it all, I see a distinction, you can change "suddenly" to "immediately after I saw the room where you died".

Comment: Remember the OP may only be able to check back here periodically, and may have trouble understanding the implications of our comment. He may also be aware of stuff like the BBC saying adverbial placement is *normally* covered by [1) initial position (before the subject) 2) mid position (between the subject and the verb or **immediately after be** as a main verb) or 3) end position (at the end of the clause).](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv202.shtml) But at the end of the day this is an *incredibly* complex aspect of English usage.

Comment: Personally I have no idea whether "competent" Indian writers have a greater tendency than other Anglophones to put the adverb before ***be***, and if so, whether there's any reason for this. I assume people who *aren't* competent speakers are much more likely to get this sort of thing "wrong" - but that's probably the same for anyone, not just Indians.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I always say to my students it is one of the biggest flaws of English which has too many people in too many regions/countries and there is no single ***authority*** to govern its usages like French or Italian. It is English's own fault. However, I find it interesting and challenging to go through this process to learn more about it. That's at least what I enjoy.

Comment: @Rathony: Well, I'm sure [les immortels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_fran%C3%A7aise) would like to think of themselves as "authorities", but in practice they don't accurately control *or* describe modern French usage (which like all languages is governed by *what people actually say*, rather than what someone says they should or do say). For my money, no other language has "authorities" that come close to, say, the *OED*, or McCawley's *The Syntactic Phenomena of English*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your point is valid. Nice conversing with you here. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could slowly be done.

This could be slowly done.

Slowly is an adverb of manner. You usually use it in end position such as this could be done slowly.

However. It can be used in mid position. Both the sentences presented above are correct.  Athough most of the grammar books state to use the adverb after the first auxiliary as in the first sentence, some people use it after the second auxiliary as in the second sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You can mostly place adverbs wherever you like. However, the basic rule comes to this:

> 1.- place the **adverb** after the correct form of *be.*
>    2.- place the **adverb** before the verb when there's no *be*.
>   3.- place the **adverb** before the verb when there's no *be* and after a *modal verb*. (*can, may, would, could, etc*)

---

> 1.- *This could be **slowly** done.*
>   2.- *You could **slowly** do this.*
>   3.- *We **slowly** do this.*

Comment: I can't endorse this answer unless it specifically points out that *This could be done **slowly*** is by far the preferred sequence for such constructions.

Comment: To FumbleFingers: sir, I agree that "...can be done slowly" is a better construction. But, let us narrow ourselves to the question: why do they out of the two constructions "... this could slowly be done" and "... this could be slowly done" prefer the former one? Is there a grammatical basis? Is "... this could be slowly done" equally correct from the grammatical point of view?

Comment: @Ale, why not add figures/charts as to the frequency per position provided (including FumbleFingers') That'd be helpful.

Comment: Is this an Indian English thing? As a UK/Canadian English speaker I'm with FumbleFingers otherwise.

Comment: @DJClayworth I don't think it is an Indian thing. A basic grammar book teaches that way. I am also with FumbleFingers but "this could be slowly done" is not wrong.

Comment: @Dinesh, was wondering, how sentence (like this one) is constructed in Indian language?

Comment: @shin: I don't think it's likely that adverbial placement in Hindi (or any other major Indian language) has any significant bearing on how IE speakers deal with it in English. More likely it's that many Indians who can "get by" using English as a *lingua franca* would like to sound more like a "native speaker", but they're in the slightly unusual position that the vast majority of their exposure to the language is through others who *also* aren't native speakers. Consequently they care more about learning "rules" even if they don't *always* apply.

Comment: I see. Will take note of this, @FumbleFingers. Thank you. I was just curious on the possibility that there may be 'overlap' between the writing 'norms' of the two languages causing different preferences, (From individual level to society level) as the question pointed out the prevalence of one over the other.

Comment: @shin: I really don't know the specifics of this one. I do know that although OP here isn't a native speaker, he's quite analytically-minded and able/willing to put considerable effort into emulating native speakers as closely as possible. If he says he sees *many English writers in India* do something, I'm happy to accept they really do. My guess is they don't so much actively promote what's effectively a "non-preferred" option; it's more that this particular issue is *so* subtle they simply don't notice what they're doing.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred placement in standard English is "This could be done slowly."  The other constructs are not wrong, but they are jarring.

In the same way that Yoda's speech is not grammatically wrong - it's just weird and nigh-on unique.

Comment: I don't agree that the first one is jarring – at least, not in all instances. For example: _We must quickly walk to the store. Our team could gradually improve._ Those don't necessarily sound jarring to me.

Comment: I wasn't claiming the construct could never be used - simply that in the specific cases asked about, it was jarring.  I agree entirely about the acceptability of * Our team could gradually improve*.  I'm much less agreeable over *We must quickly walk...*.  I've not yet managed to analyse specifically why.  "To gently go" seems fine to me, for example.  Perhaps because it has a history of literary use.